# Error encountered when installing node.js

Tags: node.js, g++, debian

I am trying to install node.js on my Debian Wheezy server. I am following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-a-mean-js-stack-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server) as a reference.

However, I am facing issues at this command.

```
sudo make install
```

I am getting

```
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-fuse-ld=gold' 
make[1]: *** [/node-v4.4.4/out/Release/mksnapshot] Error 1    
make[1]: Leaving directory `/node-v4.4.4/out'
make: *** [node] Error 2
```

I have been looking around but can't seem to find anything that helps. Can anyone help?

Comment: you need to paste the full log, including the output of `./configure` and `make`. that being said, installing Node from source is a terrible idea. unless you're really dedicated, there's no way you'll be able to keep up with new releases (which possibly fix security vulnerabilities), and it'll make a mess all over your filesystem. you should just `sudo apt-get install nodejs nodejs-legacy` instead.

Comment: @strugee thanks! its much better. i uninstalled the source installation and used your method instead